# 'super' key word error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

I am going through an Infinite Scroll Listview code available in git hub. https://github.com/weixiao1984/Android-Infinite-Scroll-Listview. 
What I found is, super key word is displayed as error in Android Studio and in Eclipse it is perfectly fine.
Please check the below code where super key word is used. Error is displayed for the line **InfiniteScrollListView.super**. I am not able to build project in Android Studio due to this error. Please help me with a work around for Android Studio. Thanks in advance.

```
 @Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    // Force the list view to accept its own type of adapter
    if (!(adapter instanceof InfiniteScrollListAdapter)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(InfiniteScrollListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + " expected");
    }
    // Pass information to adaptor
    InfiniteScrollListAdapter infiniteListAdapter = (InfiniteScrollListAdapter) adapter;
    infiniteListAdapter.setLoadingMode(loadingMode);
    infiniteListAdapter.setStopPosition(stopPosition);
    infiniteListAdapter.setInfiniteListPageListener(this);
    this.setOnScrollListener(infiniteListAdapter);
    // Workaround to keep spaces for header and footer
    View dummy = new View(getContext());
    addLoadingView(InfiniteScrollListView.super,dummy);
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    removeLoadingView(InfiniteScrollListView.super, dummy);
}
```

Add loading method

```
 //Add loading view method
private void addLoadingView(ListView listView, View loadingView) {
    if (listView == null || loadingView == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Avoid overlapping the header or footer
    if (!loadingViewVisible) {
        if (loadingMode == LoadingMode.SCROLL_TO_TOP) {
            // Add loading view to list view header when scroll up to load
            listView.addHeaderView(loadingView);
        } else {
            // Add loading view to list view footer when scroll down to load
            listView.addFooterView(loadingView);
        }
        loadingViewVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `InfiniteScrollListView` instance in your class?

Comment: The link has a library project, it has three files and one of them is 'InfiniteScrollListView class' which extends 'ListView'. The error is in 'InfiniteScrollListView class'. Please go through the link [link](https://github.com/weixiao1984/Android-Infinite-Scroll-Listview/blob/master/library/src/ca/weixiao/widget/InfiniteScrollListView.java)

Comment: I have seen the github project. Both the library and the demo. My suggestion is that if you have an instance of the `InfiniteScrollListView` in your class, you could pass it here: `addLoadingView(myInstance,dummy);` Because all the method needs is a `ListView`. Speaking in the terms of Object Oriented `InfiniteScrollListView` **IS A** `ListView` so it should work.

Comment: ok, I thought of doing this, will see if it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments. The method `addLoadingView(ListView listView, View loadingView);` requires a `ListView`. If you have an instance of the `InfiniteScrollListView`. You could pass it into this method. Because `InfiniteScrollListView` **IS A** `ListView`.